# Grails - username in a route

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, groovy, routes

What is the correct way to setup a username in a route that then goes off to a controller 'profile' and an action of 'show'. Like the way facebook does: http://www.facebook.com/username

but... if the first part of the URL is not a username do the standard route mechanism.

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
    constraints {
       // apply constraints here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting it up like this should work I would think. replicate/rename namedController to the controllers you actually have. A user named "namedController" in this example will never be shown, as non-dynamic token matches (the stuff between "/") has stronger precedence.

(And is also a logical idea, imo.)

```
"/namedController/$action?/$id?" (controller:"namedController")
"/$username" (controller:"profile", action:"show")
```

Comment: So as long as I name all my controllers first I should be ok?

Comment: correct, although they dont have to be "first". The new docs does not document the precendence rules very good, but if you take a look at [link](http://beta.grails.org/URL+mapping) its explained there somewhat.

Comment: I was looking at that doc. Should g:link be able to get to a user page? +1

Comment: One more quick followup. How do you make routes ignore /css, /js, /images etc... as soon as I add $username route it starts picking these up

Comment: static excludes = ["/images/*", "/css/*"]